# If a record exists with the same Date as another do not create the record

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, validation, date

I have a Salesforce/Visualforce page which allows my user to create entries out of a list of users by dragging them onto a sudo-schedule. Once the entry is created it will display some basic information. 
 I want to make it so that my user is unable to create an entry if a entry for that day already exists. Meaning if I add Joe Doe to the schedule to work on the 10.1.2023 and I try to add another Joe Doe record to the same day/date that I would not be able to whilst still being able to add him to all of the other possible Dates.
What would be the best approach of doing this? Would I create a Validation Rule? Duplicate Rule? Matching Rule? Do I thinker with the logic in my Controller? Could I be shown an example of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you best option is to either add logic to Controller or Trigger.

You can't refer to other records from Validation Rule.
You can't use Date fields in Duplicate Rules.

You can use `DAY_IN_MONTH` and `CALENDAR_MONTH` functions to correctly match records in SOQL

**UPDATE**
Here is the sample code based on account record.

```
Account acc;
List<Account> duplicates = [
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Entry_Date__c) = :acc.Entry_Date__c.day()
        AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Entry_Date__c) = :acc.Entry_Date__c.month()
];
```

Comment: Hey tiyq! Thanks for the fast reply, I'm not 100% sure how to actually use the two mentioned functions. Could you provide me a snippet or pseudocode? The field in the object I use as my date is called Entry_Date__c

Comment: sure, I'll add as an update

Comment: added example for you

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Make sure to consider bulkified inserts/updates; the above code will not work in that scenario.

Comment: unless you introduce separate field for day_month I think you can't bulkify this query, plus it's only used in Controller